# Serenity report do not have any REST Query

Tags: serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

We have a serenity and rest assured project.

But the test report does not generate RESTQuery button to check the request response

We query `with given().when().body().get(APIURL)`

the response comes but no rest query is found.

```
pom.xml
```

runner class

```
package test_suite;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import net.serenitybdd.cucumber.CucumberWithSerenity;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/resources/features",
        plugin = {"pretty"},
        glue = {"steps"}
)
public class CucumberTestSuite {


}
```

---

api object

```
@Step
    public void HTTPRequest(String ****, String ***8){
        String ApiUrl = method(somestring, somestring);
        response = given().when().log().body().get(ApiUrl); 
        //response = RestAssured.get(ApiUrl);
        //response = SerenityRest.when().get(ApiUrl);
    }
```

**Error while checking with SerenityRest**

```
 net.serenitybdd.core.exceptions.SerenityManagedException: net.serenitybdd.rest.decorators.request.RequestSpecificationDecorated.getDefinedFilters()Ljava/util/List;
```

***IT worked now with serenity version 1.9.26***

***IT worked now with serenity version 1.9.26***

Comment: Are you using the SerenityRest class or the RestAssured.given() method directly?

Comment: RestAssured.given() method, but used SerenityRest but showing error

Comment: check the editted code